# Prevent Main Navbar from Hiding When Hovering Over Sub-Menu Items

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to implement a horizontal navigation bar at the top of my site that will automatically hide while the user is browsing the page. I currently have it set up so that the bar will show itself once the user is near the top of the page and will continue to show itself while the user is using the bar, however, I am unable to keep the bar showing while the user browses the sub-menu items. I've tried to implement the "mouseenter" and "mouseout" functions for the submenu items, but I've not found a configuration that works.

HTML Code:

```
<body>
    <div id="nav_menu">
        <div class="container">
            <nav>
                <a id="home" href="random">G</a>
                <div id="links">
                    <a class="nav_link" href="random2">Gutenberg</a>
                    <div id="dropdown_gutenberg" class="dropdown">
                        <a class="nav_link_dropdown" href="random5">Dropdown 1</a>
                    </div>
                    <a class="nav_link" href="random3">Printing Techniques</a>
                    <a class="nav_link" href="random4">Early Typographers</a>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JavaScript Code (Using 1.9 JQuery):

```
function hidebar(){
document.getElementById("nav_menu").classList.add("hide_nav");
var main_nav = document.getElementsByClassName("nav_link");
for (var i = 0; i < main_nav.length; i++){
    main_nav[i].style.paddingBottom = "18px";
}}

function showbar(){
document.getElementById("nav_menu").classList.remove("hide_nav");
var main_nav = document.getElementsByClassName("nav_link");
for (var i = 0; i < main_nav.length; i++){
    main_nav[i].style.paddingBottom = "11px";
}}

function listenToMove(evt){
if (!nav_active && evt.pageY < 20){
    showbar();
    nav_active = true;
}
else if (nav_active && evt.pageY < 53){
    showbar();
    nav_active = true;
}
else if (nav_active && in_dropdown){
    showbar();
    nav_active = true;
}
else {
    hidebar();
    nav_active = false;
}}

var nav_active = false;

var in_dropdown = false;

var dropdowns = document.getElementById("dropdown");

document.addEventListener('mousemove', listenToMove);

for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++){
    document.dropdowns[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", function()
    {in_dropdown=true;});
    document.dropdowns[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function()
    {in_dropdown=false;});}
```

JSFiddle of Current Implementation:
https://jsfiddle.net/JGGoobers/Lz2a1xLg/#&togetherjs=F3h3yxHnQG

Any help is appreciated!